# why does sensorManager.registerListener require a handler?

Tags: android

(sensorManager is a SensorManager)
I'm trying to implement an orientation listener for my program. I declare the listener as a SensorEventListener. The API says I need to pass registerListener a SensorEventListener, Sensor, rate, and handler. What is the handler for?

Also, when I mouse over the error, it insists I use the deprecated veresion of the method for a SensorListener instead of a SensorEventListener. And this deprecated version doesn't require a handler. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

There is a non-deprecated method that dies not require a handler. See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29).

```
public boolean  registerListener  (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate);
```

The difference between the deprecated and non-deprecated methods is that the deprecated methods us an int for the sensor, while the non-deprecated ones take a `Sensor` object.